# Capifony Net::SSH::AuthenticationFailed

Tags: ssh, capifony

hope you can help me to solve this out.

On the deploy server, I have created a user `deploy` and uploaded the public key of my localhost to the server's `home/users/deploy/.ssh/authorized_keys`

However everytime I ran `cap deploy:setup`, localhost returned this message:

```
  * 2014-06-08 23:58:53 executing `deploy:setup'
  * executing "mkdir -p /var/www/projectplanner /var/www/projectplanner/releases /var/www/projectplanner/shared"
servers: ["XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX"]
connection failed for: XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX:YYYY (Net::SSH::AuthenticationFailed: Authentication failed for user deploy@XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX
```

Here is my deploy.rb:

```
set :application, "projectplanner"
set :domain,      "XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX:YYYY"
set :deploy_to,   "/var/www/projectplanner"
set :app_path,    "app"

set :repository,  "my_remote_git"
set :scm,         :git

set :user,        "deploy"

set :branch,      "release"
set :deploy_via,  :remote_cache

set :model_manager, "doctrine"

role :web,        domain
role :app,        domain, :primary => true

set :keep_releases,  3
set :ssh_options, { :keys => %w(/root/.ssh/id_rsa) }
set :use_sudo,    false

logger.level = Logger::MAX_LEVEL
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all try to connect to remote host from your machine via ssh and check if there is any errors.
Then you can try to remove the line form the deploy.rb:

> set :ssh_options, { :keys => %w(/root/.ssh/id_rsa) }

or change with the correct path for the user `deploy`

If you already solve the issue please share with us your solutions or problem detected.